# Understanding the implementation of ConvLSTM in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

In the [tensorflow implementation of convLSTM cell](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.0/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/convolutional_recurrent.py#L634) the following lines of code are written as:

```
    x_i = self.input_conv(inputs_i, kernel_i, bias_i, padding=self.padding)
    x_f = self.input_conv(inputs_f, kernel_f, bias_f, padding=self.padding)
    x_c = self.input_conv(inputs_c, kernel_c, bias_c, padding=self.padding)
    x_o = self.input_conv(inputs_o, kernel_o, bias_o, padding=self.padding)
    h_i = self.recurrent_conv(h_tm1_i, recurrent_kernel_i)
    h_f = self.recurrent_conv(h_tm1_f, recurrent_kernel_f)
    h_c = self.recurrent_conv(h_tm1_c, recurrent_kernel_c)
    h_o = self.recurrent_conv(h_tm1_o, recurrent_kernel_o)

    i = self.recurrent_activation(x_i + h_i)
    f = self.recurrent_activation(x_f + h_f)
    c = f * c_tm1 + i * self.activation(x_c + h_c)
    o = self.recurrent_activation(x_o + h_o)
    h = o * self.activation(c)
```

The corresponding equations as described in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.04214v1.pdf) are:

[image]

I am not able to see how W_ci, W_cf, W_co C_{t-1}, C_t is used in the input, forget and output gates. Where does it being used in computing the 4 gates?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you cannot find those in that implementation of ConvLSTM cell, because it not using peephole:

> Peephole connections allow the gates to utilize the previous internal
> state as well as the previous hidden state (which is what LSTMCell is
> limited to)

The [tf.keras.experimental.PeepholeLSTMCell](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/experimental/PeepholeLSTMCell) follow the equations you post above, as you can see in it [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.0/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L2602):

```
x_i, x_f, x_c, x_o = x
h_tm1_i, h_tm1_f, h_tm1_c, h_tm1_o = h_tm1
i = self.recurrent_activation(
    x_i + K.dot(h_tm1_i, self.recurrent_kernel[:, :self.units]) +
    self.input_gate_peephole_weights * c_tm1)
f = self.recurrent_activation(x_f + K.dot(
    h_tm1_f, self.recurrent_kernel[:, self.units:self.units * 2]) +
                              self.forget_gate_peephole_weights * c_tm1)
c = f * c_tm1 + i * self.activation(x_c + K.dot(
    h_tm1_c, self.recurrent_kernel[:, self.units * 2:self.units * 3]))
o = self.recurrent_activation(
    x_o + K.dot(h_tm1_o, self.recurrent_kernel[:, self.units * 3:]) +
    self.output_gate_peephole_weights * c)
```

Or more clear, if you look at [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.0/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/legacy_rnn/rnn_cell_impl.py#L1053) of [tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/nn/rnn_cell/LSTMCell):

```
if self._use_peepholes:
  c = (
      sigmoid(f + self._forget_bias + self._w_f_diag * c_prev) * c_prev +
      sigmoid(i + self._w_i_diag * c_prev) * self._activation(j))
else:
  c = (
      sigmoid(f + self._forget_bias) * c_prev +
      sigmoid(i) * self._activation(j))
```